# How to create FtpWebRequest over SSL?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, ftpwebrequest

I am trying to create a connection to a remote server to upload a file, the connection needs to be over SSL and I have only a bunch of ports available on routers from both sides. The connection seems to succeed, however the `Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();` times out. After inspecting tracing log, the following line seems suspicious:

```
System.Net Information: 0 : [7144] FtpControlStream#33675143 - Created connection from [myIP]:64230 to [theirIP]:990.
```

Although it says connection was created, I know that port 64230 is not open, and my guess is that's why it fails. So is it possible to specify which port to create a local connection from? Or maybe I'm missing something else?

[EDIT]:

I set up FTP site on IIS on my local machine for testing, to see what could possibly be going wrong, but I'm getting the same problem. What's interesting is that I can connect on pretty much any port with the same settings, except 990. I can now rule out the firewall, it doesn't seem to be the problem. Any other guesses? Here is the sample code:

```
string fileName = "file.pdf";
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://[host]:990/file.pdf");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
request.EnableSsl = true;
request.UsePassive = true;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AcceptAllCertifications;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("[host]|[username]", "[password]");
Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
const int bufferLength = 1024;
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];
int count = 0;
int readBytes = 0;
do
{
    readBytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
    count += readBytes;
}
while (readBytes != 0);

stream.Close();
requestStream.Close();

Console.WriteLine("Upload complete");
```

Comment: That shouldn't matter - both your firewall and the remote firewall are going to filter based on the port you're connecting to, not the auto-assigned port number you're connecting from. FTP then creates a second data connection: is that definitely on an open port too? Which direction is the data connection, i.e. are you using active / passive?

Comment: I have tried both active and passive, the results are identical. FileZilla upload works in passive, so if I could figure out what they are doing that I am not, I should be able to get it working.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't your connection string be:

```
ftps://[host]:990/file.pdf
```

Also I know you said you could rule out the firewall, but it often a headache with FTPS maybe this serverfault answer might be of use:

[What firewall ports do I need to open when using FTPS?](https://serverfault.com/questions/10807/what-firewall-ports-do-i-need-to-open-when-using-ftps)

Comment: ftps is not a protocol Uri constructor accepts, it's sufficient to set EnableSsl to true. Also I'm quite confident it's not firewall because it's currently off.